# Inserting variable number of variables to a sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

What I am trying to do is create a single line of code to execute sql that inserts data into whichever table the user decides. Each table will have a varying number of columns therefore I cannot specify how many ?s to put in the brackets. If anyone can find a solution, please share it with me as I am stuck as of now.

```
self.conn.execute('INSERT INTO ' + self.table + ' VALUES (?)', (self.data))
```

self.data is a list containing 3 items as of now but may change if the table is changed.

Comment: `",".join("?" * len(self.data))` produces the right number of question marks.

Comment: Whoa, 5 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could dynamically generate a string of comma-separated `?` based on the length of `self.data`, e.g.:

```
values = ", ".join("?" * len(self.data))
self.conn.execute('INSERT INTO ' + self.table + ' VALUES (' + values + ')', (self.data))
```

If you have Python 3.6 or later, using a formatted string with `execute()` would be more Pythonic and compact:

```
self.conn.execute(f'INSERT INTO {self.table} VALUES ({values})', (self.data))
```